# How to assign value returned by a function call inside another function [JS]

Tags: javascript

I am having two functions in my JavaScript code, and I want to perform some action on the basis of value returned by other function.

Here my code :-

```
function test1(){
    var radio = document.getElementByName('sample');
    for (i=0; i<radio.length; i++){
         //some code here
         return "some value on basis of above code"
    }
}

function test2(){
    var somevariable = globllysetValue;
    var returnValue = return test1();
    // some code and work according to the value in returnValue
}
```

Well I know `return` in function `test2` is not correct. so what can I do here NOW????

---

**Edit**

Here what I am Trying to do... but it do not seem to be working
http://jsfiddle.net/U6RjY/7/

EDIT2 ----- The corrected and working fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/U6RjY/9/
Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function test1(){
    var radio = document.getElementByName('sample');
     for (i=0; i<radio.length; i++){
         //some code here
         return "some value on basis of above code"
    }
}

function test2(){
    var somevariable = globllysetValue;
    var returnValue = test1();
    // some code and work according to the value in returnValue
}
```

Just remove the return.

You will notice however that in function test1, it will return the value on the first loop. So, it will stop executing.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/U6RjY/

Comment: Oh I got it, Thanks, it's working fine on jsfiddle... may be I am out of luck today..my code is having some problem.

Comment: What I am doing is : - http://jsfiddle.net/U6RjY/7/  now why this is not working??

Comment: It is not working.. in my code it is still logging `undefined`

Comment: Thanks.. there was another problem because of which it was going undefined My code is working fine now.. :)